# Can a Divine Soul Sorcerer learn a cleric cantrip at their first sorcerer level?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, cantrips

Can a Divine Soul Sorcerer learn a cleric cantrip at their first sorcerer level, when they create the character? Or only when they learn a new cantrip at a higher level?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Arguably, yes

> **Divine Magic**
>
> Your link to the divine allows you to learn spells normally associated with the Cleric class. **When your Spellcasting feature lets you learn a sorcerer cantrip or a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher**, you can choose the new spell from the cleric spell list or the sorcerer spell list. You must otherwise obey all the restrictions for selecting the spell, and it becomes a sorcerer spell for you.

and

> **Sorcerer Spellcasting**
>
> At first level, you **know**  four cantrips of your choice from the sorcerer spell list.

A literal reading of the Spellcasting Feature says that you *know* your starting spells, not that you *learn* them. But, of course, you had to learn them to know them.

I can find no official interpretation/tweet on the semantics of know/learn so I believe the ruling would come down to the GM. I spent an *embarrassingly* long time combing through Sage Advice and flipping through the PHB and XGtE looking for evidence for/against allowing Cleric cantrips to be taken by a level 1 Divine Soul Sorcerer. Like, I kind of hate myself for how far down the rabbit hole I went.

Suffice to say, none of the arguments are supported by anything other than conjecture of intent. So it's GM's call, I'd say. But I'd also say this: we're talking about cantrips at level 1 and 2. I've probably spent more time trying to figure out the answer than you will spend as a level 1 character lol....sob.

Comment: I don't have my book available, so I might be wrong, but isn't the additional spell from Divine Magic the one from the chart?  ("as shown below") That is, you don't get to choose it - and I don't think any of them are cantrips.

Comment: @Tal: You are correct. The "additional spell" is the one from the table below that text; they're all 1st-level spells. So that part of the answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Do you have a canon or tweeted source concerning the know/learn difference? Because, while they are different words and i can't say tht the answer is wrong, my mecanical understanding of the game tell me this ia a case of those two texts being written by two different people.

Comment: @Tal and V2Blast: Yeah. I missed the forest for the trees on that one. I edited the answer to remove the irrelevant second half.

Comment: You should also fix the quote from the Spellcasting feature to quote the "Cantrips" section instead of the "Spells Known of 1st Level and Higher" section, since the question's specifically about cantrips. (Though the same logic applies to your initial two 1st-level spells known.)

Comment: @rpeinhardt How far down the rabbit hole you went ... was a good thing.

Comment: For my clarification, in the text quoted for Divine Magic it says you can choose a Cleric spell from the Cleric spell list. From reading various posts aren't cantrips not allowed as they are not spells?

Comment: Cantrips are "0 level" spells. Where are you reading that they are not spells?

Comment: I know it's not canonical, but as supporting evidence, D&D Beyond works this way — you can pick Cleric-list cantrips at first level

Comment: Also, can you replace one of your sorc spells with your first level of sorc?
"Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the sorcerer spells you know and replace it with another spell from the sorcerer spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots."
So you could possibly take 2 cleric spells at first level in addition to the free one for 3 total. 
"When your Spellcasting feature lets you learn or replace"
You learned, and you replaced, two triggers.

Answer (score 0):

### The Answer is Yes.

Technically, you can learn four cleric cantrips as a level 1 Divine Soul. These become your personal arcane sorcery cantrips because you chose them thanks to the Divine Magic feature.

The Divine Magic class feature is in effect the moment you select Divine Soul as a bloodline archetype for the Sorcerer, before spell selection, so all appropriate cleric spells, including cantrips are available for a Divine Soul to choose from at level 1/creation. You can start a Divine Soul with nothing but 'converted' cleric spells, specifically, 4 cantrips and 2 level 1 spells.

The "You must otherwise obey all the restrictions for selecting the spell" is to broadly point out that you have to follow the sorcerers' rules for spell selection, such as following the sorcerer spell progression tables, having to choose a spell of a level you can actually cast, multiclass rules for spellcasters, and being allowed to replace one known spell with another when you level up as a Divine Soul.

It also has the function of converting these cleric Divine spells into Arcane spells, meaning they work with arcane foci, eliminating petty fussing over using an arcane staff to cast a fireball one round and juggling to your 'god stick' to cast Aid. Divine Soul powers come from the sorcerer, not an external entity, so you don't have to worry about 'angry deity syndrome' that can affect wayward clerics.